# Stop dpad focus going outside current fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus

My current app requires control using a D-Pad remote.

Using Focus/Select, automatic calculation of nearest neighbour works as expected but i want to limit the Up, Down, Left, Right movements to only occur in the current fragment that contains the focused view, and cancel the change of focus before it moves to another fragment.

I am programatically changing focus to a new fragment upon selecting a view.

Is this possible to do? I can only assume an onFocusChange() event would allow me to check whether the new focus is outside the fragment and return but no luck here...

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can call `setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS)` on container that holds your fragment to block focusability for all fragment descendants. To bring focusability back you can call `setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS)`

### Details:

Suppose you have `FrameLayout` containing two fragments, one on top another, and you want to limit focus navigation to `top_fragment` when it is in place and to `back_fragment` otherwise:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/back_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

First call `addOnBackStackChangedListener()` on instance of `FragmentManager` to provide backstack listener, where you can write you focusability controlling code with method `setDescendantFocusability`. You can use `getFragmentManager().findFragmentBy*` to find out what fragments are used now, what's on top etc. and set descendant focusability flags appropriately. When you are replacing `top_fragment` container, add transaction to backstack with `addToBackStack()` method. That way you will be able to change focusability settings when backstack changes, not only when you're adding fragment, but when you're popping it with BACK as well.